# Getting type 'int' is not a subtype of 'double' error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my *electric_guitars_screen.dart* file, I am getting **type 'int' is not a subtype of 'double' error**

I have taken relevant steps by either casting double variables to int or declared them as int itself.

Initially I thought that the divisions property of the RangeSlider was causing this error when I had cast it to .round() or .toInt(). I changed its value to a hardcoded integer.

However, I am still getting this error.

**My Code**

```
//import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
import 'package:musicart/widgets/text_label.dart';

import '../global_variables/global_variables.dart';
import '../widgets/animated_bottom_bar.dart';
import '../widgets/custom_appbar.dart';
import '../widgets/instrument_card.dart';
import 'instrument_detail.dart';

class ElectricGuitarsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ElectricGuitarsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ElectricGuitarsScreen> createState() => _ElectricGuitarsScreenState();
}

List<Map<String, dynamic>> guitarList = [];
List<Map<String, dynamic>> filteredGuitars = [];
//List<Map<String, dynamic>> filteredGuitars2 = [];
List<Map<String, dynamic>> filteredGuitarsByBrands = [];
//List<Map<String, dynamic>> filteredGuitarsByPrice = [];
List<String> guitarBrandList = [];
List<String> selectedBrands = [];

String sortCriterion = "relevance";

void populateGuitarList() {
  guitarList.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < instruments.length; i++) {
    if (instruments[i]["instrument"].toString().toLowerCase() == "guitar") {
      guitarList.add(instruments[i]);
    }
  }
}

void populateGuitarBrandList() {
  guitarBrandList.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
    guitarBrandList.add(guitarList[i]["brand"]);
  }
  guitarBrandList = guitarBrandList.toSet().toList();
}

double minGuitarPrice = 10000000.0;
double maxGuitarPrice = -1.0;

void findMinPrice() {
  for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
    if (guitarList[i]["price"] < minGuitarPrice) {
      minGuitarPrice = guitarList[i]["price"];
    }
  }
}

void findMaxPrice() {
  for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
    if (guitarList[i]["price"] > maxGuitarPrice) {
      maxGuitarPrice = guitarList[i]["price"];
    }
  }
}

double minSearchPrice = minGuitarPrice;
double maxSearchPrice = maxGuitarPrice;

class _ElectricGuitarsScreenState extends State<ElectricGuitarsScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _searchBoxController = TextEditingController();
  final String _hintText = "Search instruments...";
  int _currentIndex = 1;
  int count = 0;

  bool isSortFilter = false;

  RangeValues rv = RangeValues(0, 1000000);

  double _animContWidth = 0.0;
  double _animContHeight = 0.0;

  void changeSearchPrice(double minsp, maxsp) {
    setState(() {
      minSearchPrice = minsp;
      maxSearchPrice = maxsp;
      populateGuitarList();
      count++;
    });
  }

  void populateFilteredGuitars(double minp, double maxp) {
    filteredGuitars.clear();

    filteredGuitarsByBrands.clear();
    //filteredGuitarsByPrice.clear();

    if (selectedBrands.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < selectedBrands.length; j++) {
          if (guitarList[i]["brand"] == selectedBrands[j]) {
            filteredGuitarsByBrands.add(guitarList[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (selectedBrands.isEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
        if (guitarList[i]["price"] <= maxp && guitarList[i]["price"] >= minp) {
          filteredGuitars.add(guitarList[i]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      filteredGuitars.clear();
      for (int i = 0; i < filteredGuitarsByBrands.length; i++) {
        if (filteredGuitarsByBrands[i]["price"] <= maxp &&
            filteredGuitarsByBrands[i]["price"] >= minp) {
          filteredGuitars.add(filteredGuitarsByBrands[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    populateGuitarList();
    findMinPrice();
    findMaxPrice();
    minSearchPrice = minGuitarPrice;
    maxSearchPrice = maxGuitarPrice;
    rv = RangeValues(minSearchPrice, maxSearchPrice);
    sortCriterion = "relevance";
    //guitarList.sort((a, b) => a["brand"].compareTo(b["brand"]));
    populateFilteredGuitars(minSearchPrice, maxSearchPrice);
    populateGuitarBrandList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double? screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double? screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          CustomAppBar(
            screenWidth: screenWidth,
            screenHeight: screenHeight,
            searchBoxController: _searchBoxController,
            hintText: _hintText,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: screenWidth * 0.025),
                child: TextLabel(
                    width: screenWidth * 0.125,
                    labelText: "Guitars",
                    fontSize: screenWidth * 0.025),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: screenWidth * 0.025),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (!isSortFilter) {
                        _animContWidth = screenWidth * 0.95;
                        _animContHeight = screenHeight * 0.205;
                      } else {
                        _animContWidth = 0;
                        _animContHeight = 0;
                      }
                      isSortFilter = !isSortFilter;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.sort_rounded,
                    size: screenWidth * 0.05,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02)),
          (isSortFilter)
              ? AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                  width: _animContWidth,
                  height: _animContHeight,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "₹ $minGuitarPrice",
                            style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(
                              color: primaryColor,
                              fontSize: screenWidth * 0.025,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: screenWidth * 0.7,
                            child: RangeSlider(
                              min: minGuitarPrice,
                              max: maxGuitarPrice,
                              divisions: 45000,
                              values: rv,
                              labels: RangeLabels(rv.start.round().toString(),
                                  rv.end.round().toString()),
                              activeColor: primaryColor,
                              inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                              onChanged: (values) {
                                setState(() {
                                  rv = values;
                                  populateFilteredGuitars(rv.start, rv.end);
                                  count++;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "₹ $maxGuitarPrice",
                            style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(
                              color: primaryColor,
                              fontSize: screenWidth * 0.025,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02)),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: screenHeight * 0.025,
                        width: screenWidth * 0.9,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemCount: guitarBrandList.length,
                                    itemBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            right: screenWidth * 0.02),
                                        child: InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            if (!selectedBrands.contains(
                                                guitarBrandList[index])) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                selectedBrands.add(
                                                    guitarBrandList[index]);

                                                populateFilteredGuitars(
                                                    rv.start, rv.end);
                                                count++;
                                              });
                                            } else {
                                              setState(() {
                                                selectedBrands.remove(
                                                    guitarBrandList[index]);

                                                populateFilteredGuitars(
                                                    rv.start, rv.end);

                                                count++;
                                              });
                                            }
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: screenWidth * 0.2,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: (!selectedBrands.contains(
                                                      guitarBrandList[index]))
                                                  ? Colors.grey.shade200
                                                  : primaryColor,
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  const BorderRadius.all(
                                                      Radius.circular(10)),
                                            ),
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                guitarBrandList[index],
                                                style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(
                                                  color:
                                                      (!selectedBrands.contains(
                                                              guitarBrandList[
                                                                  index]))
                                                          ? primaryColor
                                                          : tertiaryColor,
                                                  fontSize: screenWidth * 0.02,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02)),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          CustomRadioButton(
                            screenWidth: screenWidth,
                            value: "relevance",
                            groupValue: sortCriterion,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                sortCriterion = value.toString();
                                guitarList.sort(
                                    (a, b) => a["brand"].compareTo(b["brand"]));
                                populateFilteredGuitars(rv.start, rv.end);
                                count++;
                              });
                            },
                            text: "Relevance",
                          ),
                          CustomRadioButton(
                            screenWidth: screenWidth,
                            value: "low to high",
                            groupValue: sortCriterion,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                sortCriterion = value.toString();
                                guitarList.sort(
                                    (a, b) => a["price"].compareTo(b["price"]));
                                populateFilteredGuitars(rv.start, rv.end);
                                count++;
                              });
                            },
                            text: "Low to High",
                          ),
                          CustomRadioButton(
                            screenWidth: screenWidth,
                            value: "high to low",
                            groupValue: sortCriterion,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                sortCriterion = value.toString();
                                guitarList.sort(
                                    (a, b) => b["price"].compareTo(a["price"]));
                                populateFilteredGuitars(rv.start, rv.end);
                                count++;
                              });
                            },
                            text: "High to Low",
                          ),
                          CustomRadioButton(
                            screenWidth: screenWidth,
                            value: "max discount",
                            groupValue: sortCriterion,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                sortCriterion = value.toString();
                                guitarList.sort((a, b) =>
                                    (a["price"] / a["mrp"])
                                        .compareTo((b["price"] / b["mrp"])));
                                populateFilteredGuitars(rv.start, rv.end);
                                count++;
                              });
                            },
                            text: "Max Discount",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02)),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(right: screenWidth * 0.025),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedBrands.clear();
                                  rv = RangeValues(
                                      minGuitarPrice, maxGuitarPrice);
                                  populateFilteredGuitars(rv.start, rv.end);
                                  count++;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Clear filters",
                                style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(
                                  color: primaryColor,
                                  fontSize: screenWidth * 0.02,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02)),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              : const SizedBox(),
          SizedBox(
            width: screenWidth,
            height: (isSortFilter) ? screenHeight * 0.615 : screenHeight * 0.8,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: screenWidth * 0.025),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: AnimationLimiter(
                      key: ValueKey("list $count"),
                      child: GridView.count(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: screenWidth * 0.01,
                        mainAxisSpacing: screenWidth * 0.01,
                        childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                        children:
                            List.generate(filteredGuitars.length, (index) {
                          return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
                            position: index,
                            columnCount: 2,
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                            child: SlideAnimation(
                              child: FadeInAnimation(
                                child: InstrumentCard(
                                    width: (screenWidth * 0.47),
                                    height: (screenWidth * 0.47) / 0.75,
                                    instrumentImageUrl: filteredGuitars[index]
                                        ["img-url"],
                                    instrumentName: filteredGuitars[index]
                                        ["name"],
                                    instrumentMrp:
                                        "₹${filteredGuitars[index]["mrp"].toString()}",
                                    instrumentPrice:
                                        "₹${filteredGuitars[index]["price"].toString()}",
                                    paddingRight: 0,
                                    innerHorizontalSymmetricPadding: 10,
                                    innerVerticalSymmetricPadding: 0,
                                    instrumentDiscount:
                                        "${(((1 - (filteredGuitars[index]["price"] / filteredGuitars[index]["mrp"])) * 100).round()).toString()}% off",
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  InstrumentDetail(
                                                      instrument:
                                                          filteredGuitars[
                                                              index])));
                                    },
                                    onWishTap: () {
                                      if (wishList
                                          .contains(filteredGuitars[index])) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          wishList
                                              .remove(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                          //count++;
                                        });
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          wishList.add(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                    onCartTap: () {
                                      if (cartList.contains(
                                              filteredGuitars[index]) ==
                                          false) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          cartList.add(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                          cartMap.addAll(
                                              {filteredGuitars[index]: 1});
                                        });
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          cartList
                                              .remove(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                          cartMap
                                              .remove(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                    isWishlisted: (wishList
                                            .contains(filteredGuitars[index]))
                                        ? true
                                        : false,
                                    isCarted: (cartList
                                            .contains(filteredGuitars[index]))
                                        ? true
                                        : false,
                                    instrument: filteredGuitars[index]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: screenHeight * 0.025)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: screenWidth * 0.025, vertical: screenHeight * 0.015),
        child: CustomAnimatedBottomBar(
          containerHeight: 56,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
          showElevation: true,
          itemCornerRadius: 10,
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          items: navBarItems,
          onItemSelected: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**What is causing this error in my code?**

Comment: where are you getting this error

Comment: can you plz reduce the question code?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I am not getting a compilation error as such, but when I try to load the screen in my emulator or phone I'm getting this error. I'm unable to spot the exact part of the code which is causing this error.

Comment: There are missing parts like `CustomRadioButton`, `CustomAppBar` `TextLabel`... are missing

Comment: debug to detect where the error is happening

Comment: @YeasinSheikh those are imported from other widgets, I have not included them in the post because the post was becoming too long.

Comment: Issue are coming from outside as i mentioned those widget, comments all and test one by one, and debug will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
   void findMinPrice() {
      for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
        if (guitarList[i]["price"] < minGuitarPrice) {
          minGuitarPrice = (guitarList[i]["price"].toString.toDouble()); 
      }
    }
    
    void findMaxPrice() {
      for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
        if (guitarList[i]["price"] > maxGuitarPrice) {
          maxGuitarPrice = (guitarList[i]["price"].toString.toDouble()); 
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already changed the `guitarList[i]["price"]` to double in my map file, but your approach is better as I can programatically convert integer prices to double. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue I've found from the provided snippet,

There will be runtime error while using `RangeSlider`

swap this value, Note this is not int issue, it is coming from others widget as I mentioned in the comment

```dart
double maxGuitarPrice = 10000000.0;
double minGuitarPrice = -1.0;
```

Comment: I have swapped this value in a function call. Funny thing is the screen is workign perfectly on web but getting this error on mobile and emulator.

Comment: I found out the function which is causing the error:
`void findMinPrice() {
  for (int i = 0; i < drumsList.length; i++) {
    if (drumsList[i]["price"] < minDrumsPrice) {
      minDrumsPrice = drumsList[i]["price"];
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Fixed the issue. The `price` of every instrument was in `int` but the `minPrice` and `maxPrice` were in `double`. So I went to the file holdinf the Map values of instruments and changed the price for each instrument to double, and it worked. Cheers.